# Proof of functional completeness and adequate of logical operators

Tags: logic, functional-equations, boolean-algebra

a) Prove that {∨, ∧, ¬} is functional complete

b) Prove that the singleton sets {|} and {↓} where

$$
\begin{array}{cc|ccccc|c}
x & y & x \mid y & & x & y & x \downarrow y \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
$$

are functional complete. The connective | is called Sheffer stroke and the connective ↓ is called Pierce arrow.

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQVNP.png)

c) Prove that the sets {∨, ∧}, {→, ∨}, {→, ∧} are not adequate sets of connectives.

Comment: And many similar posts visible on the right of the screen...

Comment: but it doesn't resolve my question..

Comment: Do you know how to prove functional completeness ?

Comment: In the linked post there is the proof that $\{ \lor, \lnot \}$ is functional complete. This means that $\land$ can be expressed with them. Thus, also $\{ \land, \lor, \lnot \}$ is complete.

Comment: For Sheffer and Peirce connectives, repeat the procedure, showing that both are able to express $\land, \lor$ and $\lnot$ (you van see Wiki's entries).